# How to listen to all content changes in tinyMCE

Tags: ios, tinymce-4

I am setting up an tinyMCE version 4.x editor to run on mobile in a WebView. I need to know about all content changes i.e. when I type new text etc. I have added listeners for NodeChange and Change but I am not getting notifications for all changes. An example is the case when I have a list item and i type text in it. All I get is the notification on the first char typed, then the notification stop until I hit return to create a new list item, then the same scenario repeats...

Is there any other way I can hook up a listener to get all content change notifications?

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole bunch of events you can hook into:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/events/#editorevents

It would seem that the one you have chosen is not granular enough for your needs so I would look for a different one (or ones) that provide you the granularity you need.  Worst case you could get notified on each keypress if need be.

Comment: i have already read the docs ...don't find anything that fits. I thought about keypress but there is just too much noise...